# Referencing Projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I am confused about how VS 2017 figures out project references. This is using the new csproj file format.

I have a solution which has numerous related class library projects in it. Those projects use other, general-purpose libraries I've written. Some of those general purpose libraries, in turn, utilize other libraries. Conceptually, the structure looks like this:

Class Library **A** -> uses supporting library **SL1** -> uses supporting library **SL1a** -> uses supporting library **X**

Class Library **B** => uses supporting library **SL2** -> uses supporting library **SL2a** -> uses supporting library **Y**

The key point is, neither Class Library **A** nor Class Library **B** utilize supporting library **X** or **Y** directly.

Yet if I don't specifically include libraries **X** & **Y** in the solution, I get resolver errors complaining about not being able to find objects defined in library **X** or **Y** when I try to compile Class Library **A** or **B**.

I thought that the `.csproj` files would take care of all this, instructing VS 2017 on how to locate the source code for supporting libraries **X** & **Y** (they're all accessible on my local file system, and the paths in the `.csproj` files all use absolute paths).

Clearly I'm missing something. It's not a big deal, of course, to add specific references to the projects for libraries **X** & **Y**. But I'd like to understand why I have to do that.

Here's an extract from the `.csproj` file of a typical Class Library **A**, which references **DatabaseJobFramework**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\WebJobs\src\DatabaseJobFramework\DatabaseJobFramework.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\CampaignSystem\src\CampaignDb\CampaignDb.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\CampaignSystem\src\CampaignMessaging\CampaignMessaging.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here's an extract for **DatabaseJobFramework.csproj**, a typical supporting library **SL1**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\WebJobs\src\ImportFramework\ImportFramework.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\WebJobs\src\JobFramework\JobFramework.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\WebJobs\src\JobMessaging\JobMessaging.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here's an extract for **ImportFramework.csproj**, a typical supporting library **SL1a**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\UtilityLibraries\src\SpecializedCollections\SpecializedCollections.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\UtilityLibraries\src\SystemUtils\SystemUtils.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="C:\Programming\DataLibraries\src\dBaseIII\dBaseIII.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**SystemUtils**, a typical library **X**, does not depend on any code I've written; all of its references are to system libraries (e.g., `Microsoft.CSharp`, `System`)

**Additional Info**

The workaround I'm using involves adding a reference to project **X** (class library **X**; **SystemUtils** in my example) to the solution, even though it is already referenced in the `.csproj` file for class library **SL1a** (**ImportFramework**, in my example).

Put another way, why do I have to include **SystemUtils** explicitly in the solution, even though I've already included **ImportFramework** in the solution, and >>it's<< `.csproj` file contains a reference to **SystemUtils**?

Comment: This should not be true.  If project A -> B -> C, A depends on B, and nothing from C, then project A's CSproj should only have to reference B.  If A references a type in C, then it will also need to reference C.  Project B's csproj will have reference to C, but unless A depends on something directly in C, A should not need to reference C

Comment: what exactly are you asking anyway?

Comment: @Kritner, project A's csproj file doesn't reference project X (in my example, as you can see, there's no such reference in the ItemGroup). The problem is that if project X isn't included in the solution -- even though it's not referenced by project A -- the solution won't compile. You get a whole bunch of "can't resolve" errors during the build. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: You're using too many project samples and it's getting difficult to follow.  If you have A -> B -> C, and you're trying to ***compile*** "B", within the solution, then "C" needs to be a part of the solution.  "A" has no reference on "C", but it does on "B", in order to compile "B", we need "C".

Comment: @MarkOlbert am I right in assuming that the top-level project builds fine using `msbuild A.csproj` from the developer command prompt but does not build from within VS? (VS is special here since all projects need to be part of the solution)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the question, because it contains many unimportant details. I do not understand what is the difference between the imports chain of A and the B chain? If they are the same and do not affect each other, one can give up on them.

Comment: In addition, it is difficult to follow the SL1a which becomes something else. If you use the name SL1a, nothing happens if you change its name in the example of csproj.

Comment: In addition, it is difficult to follow the SL1a which becomes something else. If you use the name SL1a, nothing happens if you change its name in the example of csproj.